# How to combine insert code and bar code code together in android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have two sets of code. Both sets require the same name `onActivityResult` but I'm not sure how to combine them without clashing.

The two sets of code are:

1. **1st Set**: Users are required to click on the no-image `ImageView` to select an image from their mobile device and then it will display the image that they have selected.
2. **2nd Set**: Users are required to click a Button to scan a barcode. It will open a camera for the user to scan the barcode and after scanning, it will display the number from the barcode.

Here is the code for two sets:

**1st Set of Code:**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Check for Image Request , If user get the image is ok, and the image is not null
    if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null){

        //Put the image data into this mImageUri
        mImageUri = data.getData();

        //This line take the data from mImageUri and load into mImageView so basically changing the uri to image
        Picasso.with(this).load(mImageUri).into(ItemORFoodImg);
    }
}
```

**2nd Set of Code:**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    final IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    if(result != null){
        if(result.getContents() == null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Result Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            AlertDialog.Builder alertdialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertdialogbuilder.setMessage(result.getContents()+"\n\nWant to add as new item?");
            alertdialogbuilder.setTitle("ResultScanned");
            alertdialogbuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    String barcode = result.getContents();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BarcodeTest.this,AddNewItem.class);
                    intent.putExtra(BarID, barcode);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            alertdialogbuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertdialogbuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
    else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    }
}
```

Can someone help me combine these two code snippets without clashing?

Comment: Are they part of same Activity? By merging you mean having only one onActivityResult() , rigth?

Comment: yes they are in the same activity

Comment: Is it possible to seperate too ?

Comment: @jun It is so simple.I mean you want to one onActivityResult on both of the click.right?Simply pass different result code for both cases and check the rsponse code in onActivity Result.Hope you unrstand my view.So you can combine on on eon Acitivity Result.

Comment: Yup differentiate on the basis of Result Code.

Comment: Sorry, Im new to programming. Is it something like If response Code == 1 it will execute this section of code, if response code == 2 it will execute another section of code ? So its a if-else statement in the OnactivityResult?

Comment: Maybe can give some examples with codes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use IntentService.
You can create two java class one for insert code and one for QR code.
When pressed ImageView go to insert code class and when pressed button go to QR code class.
And then pass data to your Activity.
Follow this link
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService